# How to Only Run Migrations if Using SQL Server and not In-Memory

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework Core using SQL Server with migrations. I am also using the In-Memory and SQL-Lite In-Memory database connections in my integration tests.

How can I only run migrations when I am using a SQL Server connection? I can't see a way of detecting the type of data store based on an `DbContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityFramework Core has dependency injection built in. You can check the database provider by getting it as a service like so:

```
if (dbContext.GetService<IDatabaseProviderServices>() is SqlServerDatabaseProviderServices)
{
    await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MigrationBuilder.ActiveProvider` property to determine whether to execute the `Up` method in a migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    if (migrationBuilder.ActiveProvider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
    {
        CreateTable(....
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers#one-migration-set

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option...

```
if (db.GetService<IDatabaseProviderServices>()
    .InvariantName == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
{
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: This is true for In-Memory and SQLite too.